# How to style a div to fill the entire contents of a table cell?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style the divs to fill the entire contents of the table cell. That means that the background color should fill the height of the table cell. How can I get the div to fill the height of the table cell?

```
<style>
    body { background-color: #ccc; }
    table, tr, td { border: 2px solid #00f; }
    td > div { background-color: #fff; color: #f00; padding: 5px;}
</style>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="position: relative; z-index: 1000">
                line<br />line<br />line
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div style="position: relative; z-index: 1000">fill contents</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The background color should fill the height of the "fill contents" table cell:

[image]

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjd6x/) to play with.

Also, the reason I am asking this is because I **can't** style the td tag due to a workaround in my JavaScript.

**Update:** This may help to visualize my specific problem: http://jsfiddle.net/pjd6x/8/ There is an overlay that is appearing on top of the table (intentionally) and below the divs (also intentional), but I would like the divs to be the same height (to look as if they are filling the contents of the tds).

Comment: I *think* this is in fact impossible because a table cell can't have `position: relative`, thus you can't absolutely position the div in it, and `width/height: 100%` won't work correctly across browsers. Interested to see whether anything comes up

Comment: Why do you not add this css to the tabel-cells?

Comment: I think Pekka is right. Do you need the text to be at the top? Try applying `vertical-align: top` to your `td`.

Answer (score 1):

If your elements can have a fixed height:

```
td > div {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    color:#FF0000;
    padding:5px;
    display:table-cell;
    height:80px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: that may be what I have to do (specify a fixed height)...however, I can't use `display:table-cell` since that's part of the problem that I am avoiding, which means I can't use `vertical-align:middle` but I would still like to align the text in the middle...hmmm...not sure what I should do

Comment: You could try to explain what problem you are try to avoiding. Maybe this specific problem is only a symptom of anything bigger...

Comment: Btw... whats about a background-color for the table?! Can't imagine that it won't work o_O

Comment: Background-color on the parent would work fine for me, except that the children are anchors. Can't have half the button not clickable. :(